# Send email workflow with custom column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am very new with SharePoint Designer and i need your helps to create an email send to Assigner when a task has been added in our Work Task in SharePoint.
I have four custom column named:
Project Title, Engineer, Drafter, and Work Sources.

I want to create a workflow that send email to Drafter with the following:
Email Subject: Project title
**Email body**
Project title:
Engineer:
Work Source:

Thank you very much,
Dennis

Answer (score 1):

Go a head in SPD and click a workflow-->List workflow-->give the name that you want-->click action button on the ribbon-->find send email

Comment: Thank you, the workflow worked in the first time, but after i edited it, it is no longer working. It indicated the "internal Status" Suspended???. How do i know the workflow is published to the pages (SharePoint Online)that i wanted it to be?

Comment: In SharePoint Online, how do i know that this workflow is associated with the pages I want it to be?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491 First download , go to your site and open through SPD

Answer (score 1):

As Explained by Mathew, you can create rules and set IF conditions based on your specific criteria. You can setup the email notification task to be sent to your list column for 'Drafter' and use the fields in the email body display the Project Title dynamically. Make sure your workflow is attached to your list. And also make sure that the workflow is configured to run when an item is created and modified.